# cygwin extracting to another directory

Tags: linux

I have a file, in Windows, called `php_0.27.tar.gz` and want to extract it to `C:\Program Files\PHP\script` through Cygwin using this command:

```
tar -xf php_0.27.tar.gz -C /Program Files/PHP/script
```

But I got an error saying:

> tar: Files: Not found in archive

I tried this command too:

```
tar -xf php_.tar.gz --directory /Program Files/PHP/script
```

But I got an other error saying:

> tar: php_0.27.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

So I tried:

```
tar -xf php_.tar.gz --directory C:/Program Files/PHP/script
```

But I failed and now I am stuck. I need help

Answer (score 0):

The space in the directory name Program Files is the source of the error ; putting the whole path to directory between quotes like this "C:/Program Files/PHP/script" solve the problem